# How can I keep the state in an item from a ListView (like the item selected) when I scroll the list?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a problem with a listview; I created two ListView in two fragments to show them in the same Layout

And when I select an item from the left ListView, automatically refresh the right ListView according to the item selected.
The thing is that when I select an item from the right ListView, it changes the color to green, and that's ok because I programmed in that way, and if I select another item it has to change to green too, and keep the original color from the first selected item, like I show you in the image below

[First selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZPUc.png)

but when I scroll the left ListView to select another item, and I return to the top of the list, the state of the item selected has gone,as I show below

[The new view, without keep the state selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGzsk.png)

and I know the reason is because the list view recycles its items views, but I've tried many things to try to keep the state no matter if I scroll the list, but I could't achieve this goal.
And at this point, I don't know what i have to change from my code; I show you the important parts; if you need more information o more from my code tell me please.

The constructor of an ListItem:

```
    public class Lista_Item {
        private String color, texto;
        private String textoSuperior, textoInferior;
        boolean seleccionado = false;

    public Lista_Item(String color, String textoSuperior, String textoInferior, boolean seleccionado) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.color = color;
        this.textoSuperior = textoSuperior;
        this.textoInferior = textoInferior;
        this.seleccionado = seleccionado;
    }

    public Lista_Item(String color, String texto) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.color = color;
        this.texto = texto;
    }

    public String getTextoSuperior() {
        return textoSuperior;
    }

    public String getTextoInferior() {
        return textoInferior;
    }

    public boolean getSeleccionado() {
        return seleccionado;
    }

    public String getTexto() {
        return texto;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }


    public void setSeleccionado(boolean seleccionado) {
          this.seleccionado = seleccionado;
         }



}
```

The adapter:

```
private class ListAdapter extends  ArrayAdapter<Lista_Item> {

private int mResourceId = 0;
private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;

public ListAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Lista_Item> listaItem) {
    super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, listaItem);
    mResourceId = resource;
    mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}


@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;

    if (convertView == null) {

        convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(mResourceId, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvItemListaColor);
        holder.l = (LinearLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.layoutColor);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }else{
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    Lista_Item pedido = listItems.get(position);
    holder.name.setText(pedido.getTexto());
    holder.l.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(pedido.getColor()));
    holder.name.setTag(pedido);

    return convertView;
}

private class ViewHolder {
    TextView name;
    LinearLayout l;
}
```

}

The event OnItemClickListener:

```
public AdapterView.OnItemClickListener d = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> list, View view, int pos, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if(listener!=null){
        listener.onPedidoSeleccionado((Lista_Item)list.getAdapter().getItem(pos));
    }

    String[] item = parts[pos].split("!");
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Ha pulsado el item " +item[0], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.d("Color","Color = "+colorSaved);

    if (currentSelectedView != null && currentSelectedView != view) {
        unhighlightCurrentRow(currentSelectedView, colorSaved);
        colorSaved = item[1];
    }

    currentSelectedView = view;
    highlightCurrentRow(currentSelectedView);
    colorSaved = item[1];
}
```

};

And the methods that I used above:

```
private void unhighlightCurrentRow(View rowView, String color) {
        rowView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#"+color));
    }

    private void highlightCurrentRow(View rowView) {
        rowView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

    }
```

**Please, any help???**

Comment: Change the title of your question, so that it makes more sense.

Comment: Hi, I'm, sorry but for some reason this didn't let me to write my own title, and it wrote another from other questions or topics, I think, but the question is: **How can I keep the state in an item from a ListView (like the item selected) when I scroll the list**

Comment: It's done, I'm sorry for the mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a object to set a arrayList, this object be like this

```
 `public class FormaPagoVO {

    String id;
    Boolean anadir; 
    create the variables do you want whit getter and setter.....
    public Boolean getAnadir() {
        return anadir;
    }

    public void setAnadir(Boolean anadir) {
        this.anadir = anadir;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}`
```

then in your activity something like this, and pass the array to adapter

```
 List<FormaPagoVO> arrayForma = new ArrayList<FormaPagoVO>();
  FormaPagoAdapter adapterDos = new FormaPagoAdapter(getApplicationContext(),arrayForma);
 listViewForma.setAdapter(adapterDos);
```

in the getView of the adapter this

```
 if(getItem(position).getAnadir()){ // validate if check de listview or not and change de background
            imgClientes.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.seleccion1);
        }else{
            imgClientes.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.seleccion);
        }
```

int the click of listview

```
imgClientes.setOnClickListener( new android.view.View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                if(getItem(position).getAnadir()){
                    // vuelve a blanco

                    getItem(position).setAnadir(false);
                }else{
                    // coloca verde

                    getItem(position).setAnadir(true);
                }
            }
        });
```

thats all

Comment: Hi, excuseme, could you be more especific in some things, I mean, for example, I have to put off the code related to ViewHolder and just place yours?? And where is the right place to put your code exactly; I mean, outside from **if(convertView==null)** or in an else statement... Could explain this part please? I already tried to place your code according to my needs but it doesn't work properly, so I think that I'm doing something wrong...

Comment: hi no replace for my code, only see im use de objectVO to set de state of item in the position clicekd on listview, when user click in item i set the object.anadir = true, when de listview pass for that position answer is true or false for make something